# Every vertices in this mesh are not connected to one another

Tags: mesh, edit-mode, vertices

[image]

Is there a way to fix this other than going through each one by hand or make it from scratch?

Comment: search merge vertices by distance blender

Answer (score 1):

Yes. What do you need to do is called “merge by distance,“ formerly “remove doubles.”

1. Go to edit mode.
2. Go to selection mode: vertex.
3. Select all.
4. Menu Mesh -> Merge -> By distance.

And as the French hens say, voila.